# how to render component from .map() in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, jsx

So im trying to not duplicate code and probably over complicating this but im very curious if there is a way for a system like this to work

```
        <Drawer anchor="right" open={sideBarOpen} onClose={toggleSideBar}>
          <List className={classes.sideBar}>
            {[
              ["test1", <LockOpenIcon />],
              ["test2", <LockOpenIcon />],
              ["test2", <LockOpenIcon />],
            ].map(({ text, icon }, index) => (
              <Fragment key={index}>
                <ListItem button>
                  <ListItemIcon>{icon}</ListItemIcon>
                  <ListItemText primary={text} />
                </ListItem>
                <Divider />
              </Fragment>
            ))}
          </List>
        </Drawer
```

where I map over an array of pairs of [text, iconComponent] and then render the iconComponent in the following element. this is producing no errors (but also not rendering anything in the ) and if theres not a way then thats cool but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, and you've mostly done it right. You just used object destructuring (`{text, icon}`) where you should have used iterable destructuring (`[text, icon]`):

```
<Drawer anchor="right" open={sideBarOpen} onClose={toggleSideBar}>
    <List className={classes.sideBar}>
        {[
            ["test1", <LockOpenIcon />],
            ["test2", <LockOpenIcon />],
            ["test2", <LockOpenIcon />],
        ].map(([ text, icon ], index) => (
            <Fragment key={index}>
                <ListItem button>
                    <ListItemIcon>{icon}</ListItemIcon>
                    <ListItemText primary={text} />
                </ListItem>
                <Divider />
            </Fragment>
        ))}
    </List>
</Drawer>
```

However, if the values are hardcoded like that, you might consider abstracting the repeated part of that into its own component:

```
const MyListItem = React.memo(({text, icon}) => (
    <ListItem button>
        <ListItemIcon>{icon}</ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText primary={text} />
    </ListItem>
));
```

*(The `React.memo` is just because I figure this doesn't change unless `text` or `icon` changes.)*

Then it's:

```
<Drawer anchor="right" open={sideBarOpen} onClose={toggleSideBar}>
    <List className={classes.sideBar}>
        <MyListItem text="test1" icon={<LockopenIcon/>} />
        <Divider />
        <MyListItem text="test2" icon={<LockopenIcon/>} />
        <Divider />
        <MyListItem text="test3" icon={<LockopenIcon/>} />
    </List>
</Drawer>
```

Comment: :facepalm: I was hoping it was not something that obvious haha anyways thanks for the help and advice I will defo move that into its own component.